# What is the difference between a Hidden Markov Model and a Mixture Markov Model?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

From what I understand, Hidden Markov Models are those that relate observable and unobservable states, whilst Mixture Markov Models are techniques to cluster sequences according to which Markov model out of a set of them is able to approximate it better.

However, I am having trouble understanding boundaries between both terms. Can I define a Hidden Markov Chain without following the Mixture approach, and conversely, can I have a Mixture Model without considering hidden states?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please show me the source of your understanding of Mixture Markov models?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with what you call mixture Markov models. However, as I say further in this answer, some people call hidden Markov models, dynamical mixture model. It is possible that other people refer to Mixture Markov model then. I would be happy if you could indicate where you have read this term.

The previous answer to this question states things that are somewhat inaccurate about the relationship between mixture models and HMMs. What follows aims at clarifying this.

Mixtures models are simply a weighted sum of probability distributions, nothing more:

$P(X|\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^M w_i p_i(X|\theta_i)$, with $\sum_{i=1}^M w_i = 1$

$M$ is the number of components in the mixture. A random variable can follow a mixture model the same way it follows a probability distribution.

Hidden Markov models (HMM) are far more sophisticated models and mixture models can be a part of these models.

A HMM is based on a Markov Chain of states (said hidden states). It does not model a random variable but a time series (an ordered sequence of values, multidimensional or not). Each state of the Markov chain is associated with a probability distribution that can also be a mixture of distribution (here is the only point where the 2 concepts connect!)

At time $t=0$ a state is drawn from an initial probability mass function. The observation at time $t_0$ is assumed to follow (or to have been generated) by the probability distribution (or mixture depending on the case) associated to this drawn state.
At time $t=1$, the system enters a new hidden state that is drawn from a transition matrix and the same procedure is repeated.

Hidden Markov models are sometimes called Dynamical Mixture Models (as in this [technical report](http://publications.idiap.ch/downloads/reports/2007/le-idiap-rr-07-02.pdf)) because, when states are associated to mixtures of probability distributions, they can somehow be seen as a mixture model that dynamically changes over time. However, these changes are modeled via a transition matrix and are fully part of what a HMM is.

Opposite to what is said in the other answer, an HMM can be without mixture with any number of states (and even an infinite number of states). An HMM with a unique state is basically a mixture model, and if that mixture model has only 1 component, it is a simple probability distribution.

Comment: The OP did say "Mixture **Markov** Model". While I'm not familiar with a technique of that specific name, I think it's clear that he/she wasn't talking about generic mixture models.

Comment: Yes I got disturbed by the previous answer that inaccurately states things about HMMs which makes things very confusing. I was just aiming at clarifying this. I am going to add a point on this as I'm not familiar neither with any technique with this name (besides simple mixture models)

Comment: What do you mean by 1 component of HMM? Can you explain how do u get output values from different probability distribution( from hidden state/states) without mixing it ?

Comment: I agree with your good explanation of mixture model but please provide justification of your -1.( HMM without mixture model). We do need to have mixture to get output values.

Comment: @ArpitSisodia "What do you mean by 1 component of HMM?" - I did not write this. I said that an HMM with a number of hidden states equal to 1 is equivalent to a mixture model (it is basically equivalent to the emission distribution associated with this unique state). A mixture with a number of components equal to one (degenerate case) is a simple probability distribution.
You understanding of HMM is not accurate from what you write. You are confusing the transition matrix that allows to transit between states and the emission probabilities that can be mixture models or simple distributions.

Comment: @ArpitSisodia Take a discrete HMM with 3 states. A probability mass function (pmf) is assigned to each state. Say State 1 is assigned the pmf [1, 0, 0], State 2 is assigned the pmf [0,1,0], and State 3 the pmf [0,0,1]. Assume the transition matrix to be [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]] and the possible outputs (vocabulary as we are in discrete case) to be [A,B,C]. Assume the initial state pmf to be [1,0,0]. Then you HMM will produce outputs ABCABCABCABC... This HMM has no mixture model involved.

Comment: @Eskapp, good! how can u assume transition matirx? According to Hidden markov, the system would be in all 3 states(Hidden). Transition probabilities can't be [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,1]. so one has to come up with mixture model.See the actual way of calculating output values. https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=8230692877620938204#editor/target=post;postID=4641255019893596724;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=3;src=postname

Comment: Your point of transition matirx is completely absurd. Do u understand meaning of having such transition matrix? You are putting your state machine into infinite loop. Do some maths bro. :P .

Comment: in your example only, if you have transition probabilities [.3,.2,.5], [.4,.4,.2],[.1,.3,.6]. dont you need a mixture model to calculate output values. If have to have a mixture model to get output values, bro!!

Comment: @ArpitSisodia A model cannot be absurd, it is only a models. The values I chose were meant for an example, nothing more. It is a valid HMM. The transition matrix is only a collection of pmf (the k-th row represents the pmf controlling the transition of the system from the k-th state at time t to the next state at time t+1. There is no mixture model involved there.

Answer (score -2):

I dont think there is any difference between Hidden Markov Model( HMM) and Mixture Markov Model. There are HMMs and Gaussian Mixture models( GMMs).Please show me where have you read about any difference?

HMM is a kind of mixture model when you have to calculate output value from the hidden states. For example you have 2 hidden states h1 and h2 with participation probabilities of .3,.7 respectively. Lets say, The output value distribution from h1 is p1 and h2 is p2. Thus using concept of mixture model, you get output value as-

.3 X p1 + .7 X p2 ( which is nothing but the combination of 2 different distributions; mixture model).

Mixture Models have nothing to do with hidden states. Hidden markov model uses, forward algo, Viterbi algo and baum welch algo in its implementation, and gives its parameters; transition +emission probabilities+ viterbi sequence( states participation probabilities) .  You have to have a fixture model if you want to get output value from these parameters.Like in our example it was- .3* emission distribution1 + .7* emission distribution2)

Comment: "HMM can be without mixture if hidden state is 1" - No, HMMs can be without mixtures with any number of states

Comment: @Eskapp , how will you get output values. Without mixing different output distribution from hidden states.

Comment: Check my comment in my answer. I'll remove the -1 vote when you correct your answer. It was meant to make you react so we are able to have this discussion :) As I can see from what you write, you have some misunderstanding/confusion with the HMM concept. It's not an easy model to understand and I would like to prevent spreading inaccuracies about these models.

Comment: I know it's not easy to understand,but I have worked on many HMM models in Pharma and do have HMM implementation knowledge end to end :) . Perhaps you are not clear about different steps in HMM and just have overview of it. Please go through these links/papers-    https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.in/2017/02/hidden-markov-model-session-1.html   ,https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.in/2017/03/hidden-markov-model-session-2.html

Comment: @Eskapp- please let me know if u have any doubt in understanding this paper. https://www.cs.umb.edu/~rvetro/vetroBioComp/HMM/Rabiner1986%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Hidden%20Markov%20Models.pdf , I had done a lot of research in HMM.

Comment: I'm sorry that you took my previous comment so personal, it was not the goal. Let's debate with ideas, not with titles or grades. I do not doubt that you've worked with HMMs. But as you started, let me introduce myself too: In less than a month, I will be defending my PhD thesis having for title "Proportional data modeling with HMMs". It compiles 5 years of research different techniques for leaning/training HMMs, including work on mixture models and let to the publication of several articles (some still in revision). http://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/hd/e/Epaillard:Elise

Comment: Citing you own blog as a source is quite unfair, as for the other paper, I know it very well and it doesn't state that HMMs are mere mixture models.
"participation probabilities" is not a term that I've seen in any publication about HMMs. An HMM with 2 states, in the general case, has its transitions regulated through a 2x2 transition matrix.
Here is the most important point actually! HMMs take into account the order in which the data samples are observed. A mixture model does not. That is why for HMM there is the need for more parameters and for the Markovian assumption.

Comment: I will stop this debate here as I think we both presented our points, and leave it to the community to make this question live the way it has to live. I hope other people from the research community will stop by and give their input about these models.
Best of luck my friend! Nothing here is to be taken personal, we're just here to debate, learn, and grow together!